# reject all outstanding promises

Tags: angularjs

I have a situation where I have a number of promises in a service using the $q service. On location change I would like to reject all outstanding promises to prevent any chained promises from running. Is this possible?

Any thoughts greatly appreciated

C

Comment: why not store the promises in an array and fulfill via a function call. then at any time you can "pause" the processing of the promises.

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is, on certain activity cancel a promise. with $http you can pass a timeout promise to cancel any active/pending promises.

e.g. below

```
app.factory("movies", function($http, $q){

    var getById = function(id){
        var canceller = $q.defer();

        var cancel = function(reason){
            canceller.resolve(reason);
        };

        var promise =
            $http.get("/api/movies/slow/" + id, { timeout: canceller.promise})
                .then(function(response){
                   return response.data;
                });

        return {
            promise: promise,
            cancel: cancel
        };
    };

    return {
        getById: getById
    };

});
```

and you can call this cancel function from wherever you want

```
   <button ng-click="cancel(request)">Cancel</button>
```

read more about this [here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/04/24/canceling-http-requests-in-angularjs.aspx)

Comment: did the answer helped?

Answer (score -1):

I think you could use $q.all() method to manage a set of chained promises.